# Set Node.js Environment Variable (NODE_ENV) in iisnode to Production/Development/Test

Tags: node.js, iis

How do we tell iisnode to run our Node.js application environment in production/development/test?

We have successfully gotten our Node.js app running with iisnode but `process.env.NODE_ENV` is coming out as 'undefined'.

At the moment, our web.config file is written this way:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="app">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="node_modules" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>    

  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="NODE_ENV" value="production" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I've not had coffee yet this morning, but isn't that supposed to be `<iisnode node_env="production" />` inside the system.webserver section?

Comment: Hi @JoachimIsaksson, you are right! Tested it and it worked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Joachim is right above that adding `<iisnode node_env="production" />` to web.config allows control over the NODE_ENV value. Another way is to add the `iisnode.yml` file next to your web.config, and in there spcify the NODE_ENV value as `node_env: production`. See other settings you can use in iisnode.yml at https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/iisnode.yml

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of clarity the `web.config` file would look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>

    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="app">
          <match url="/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <add segment="node_modules" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>    

    <iisnode NODE_ENV="production" />            <=== Add env required here
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: NODE_ENV="production" should be in lower case "node_env"