# Environment variables not being set when deploying to Azure Cloud Service via Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, azure, deployment, azure-cloud-services

Having a few issues with environment variables in Azure Cloud Services.
I'm trying to set a "NODE_ENV" environment variable during deployment via the *ServiceDefentition.csdef* file.

The variable is to be read in by my node.js app via process.env.NODE_ENV.

The documentation for this isn't very extensive (as it appears to be a very simple thing to do) but this is what I have been following: [link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg557552.aspx#Runtime) [link2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common/)

The section of the ServiceDefinition file I have is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="userApiServer" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="userApiWebRole" vmsize="Large">
    ...
    <Runtime>
      <Environment>
        <Variable name="NODE_ENV" value="dev" />
      </Environment>
    </Runtime>
    ...
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

I've tried numerous variations; setting the env variable under a startup task instead on runtime, using xpaths to configuration settings but they just don't seem to be creating the env variables for me.

When messing around with the xpaths approach I did find that my configuration settings were being created on the instance, so the definition file is being read.

Are there any common (or uncommon) gotcha's or hidden details that I'm missing because for something apparently very simple I'm having a lot of trouble with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct to set `node_env` variable in `web.config` and `iisnode.yml` as @AIDAN CASEY said.

Additionally, we can leverage pure Node.js 3rd part module [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Just need to create a file named `.env` with the content:

```
node_env=production
```

include and initialize the module in Nodejs script:

```
require('dotenv').load();
```

Comment: Sorry for the follow up question, but is it possible to use xpaths (or similar) to pull in configuration settings when using WebConfig when creating the environment variables; similar to how it is achieved in the ServiceDefinition?And if so, would this approach dynamically change the environment variables when the configuration is changed?

Comment: If you mean that you want configure custom settings in `.cscfg` and `.csdef` files and which will set in node.js runtime, then you can get the settings in Nodejs script. I think you can leverage [azure.RoleEnvironment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/master/examples/service-runtime.md) in azure sdk for node. But it is only available in Worker Role.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it be editing either do it in web.config or iisnode.yml. Check out this answer

[Set Node.js Environment Variable (NODE_ENV) in iisnode to Production/Development/Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486804/set-node-js-environment-variable-node-env-in-iisnode-to-production-development)